How to add dynos on newly created heroku app
I am trying to deploy build on heroku, its a nodejs app, i have pipeline that gets trigger on push
here is the pipeline
image: node:18

pipelines:
branches:
dev:
- step:
name: Build Application - (Dev)
script:
- cd backend
- npm install
- npm run build

  - step:
        name: Create Artifact (Dev)
        script:
          - cd backend
          - git archive --format=tar.gz dev -o application.tar.gz
        artifacts:
          - backend/application.tar.gz

  - step:
      name: Deploy to Heroku (Dev)
      deployment: Staging
      script:
        - pipe: atlassian/heroku-deploy:2.3.0
          variables:
            HEROKU_API_KEY: $HEROKU_API_KEY
            HEROKU_APP_NAME: $HEROKU_APP_NAME_TEST
            # JWT_SECRET_KEY: $JWT_SECRET_KEY
            ZIP_FILE: backend/application.tar.gz
            WAIT: "true"
      caches:
        - node

on last step Deploy to Heroku (Dev) it is showing error
Status: Downloaded newer image for bitbucketpipelines/heroku-deploy:2.3.0
WARNING: New version available: atlassian/heroku-deploy '2.3.0' to '2.4.0'
INFO: Creating Heroku sources...
INFO: Uploading binary sources from backend/application.tar.gz
INFO: Starting a new build in Heroku...
✖ Failed to upload binary sources. Expected HTTP Status 201, got 404. Error message: {"id":"not_found","message":"The requested API endpoint was not found. Are you using the right HTTP verb (i.e. GET vs. POST), and did you specify your intended version with the Accept header?"


i guess this is due there is no dyno in my this app, i am trying to add basic dyno type to this but there is no option to add dyno

Heroku api key for bitbucket deployment variables crated from
https://dashboard.heroku.com/account/applications -> Authorizations
that i filled on the bitbucket deployment variables

There is minor issue, i was not adding all the variables in bitbucket's deployment pipelines. I added the variables and deployed the build.
After sucessfull deployment, now there is option to change the dynos as well
